# Is it possible to override an inherited method with type parameter List<Animal> with List<Dog>?

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm having trouble changing the type parameter of an inherited method.

```
abstract class Animal {
    abstract List<Animal> animalList();
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    @Override
    public List<Dog> animalList() {
        ...
        ...
    }
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
    @Override
    public List<Cat> animalList() {
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

All animal subclasses need to implement a method `animalList`. What's the best practice of doing this if i want the best possible code regarding readability and maintainability? Please note that this is extremely simplified i comparison to the actual project.

Comment: You don't need the method overrides.  Your lists all derive from the same list: the one in your abstract class.  Polymorphism insures that you can always treat your cats as cats and your dogs as dogs (by casting them to the actual runtime type), but they're all `Animal` objects.  That's kinda the whole point of inheritance.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for your fast response. It seems my IDE still wants me to override the abstract method when i remove the overrides: "Dog is not abstract and does not override abstract method animalList() in Animal". Do you mean that i don't need to declare the abstract method in the superclass and instead implement it in all subclasses without inheriting it from Animal?

Comment: Here's a question that might lead to better answers. On the consumer/calling side of this code, do you want a `List<Animal>` or do you want a `List<Dog>`?

Comment: @Zymus I suspect that i get the same data out of `List<Animal>` as in `List<Dog>` but ultimately i want a List<Dog> for better readabilty of my code. Also i have no clue how getting data out of `List<Animal>` instead of `List<Dog>` affects runtime performance and such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what the best solution is, but I would do the following:

```
import java.util.List;
abstract class Animal {
    abstract <T extends Animal> List<T> animalList();
}
```

...

```
import java.util.List;
public class Dog extends Animal {
    @Override
    List<Dog> animalList() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

...

```
import java.util.List;
public class Cat extends Animal{
    @Override
    List<Cat> animalList() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Though the working solutions are already provided, I'll put some useful references that might be helpful.

The reason why you cannot "return dogs or cats as animals" is that **they are wrapped in a collection** (`java.util.List` in this case).

F.e. you CAN write this way:

```
    abstract class Animal {
        abstract Animal[] animalArray();
    }

    public class Dog extends Animal {
        @Override
        public Dog[] animalArray() {
            //
        }
    }

    public class Cat extends Animal {
        @Override
        public Cat[] animalArray() {
            //
        }
    }
```

Why can't you do the same for `List`s?

Because in Java arrays are covariant, but generic types (`Collection<E>`) are invariant.

There is a great explanation on this topic in the best Java book, I've read - "Effective Java" (now there is a [3rd edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134685997)) by J. Bloch (*Item 28: Prefer Lists to Arrays*).

The good working solution is provided by @Zymus, using the trick so-called "*recursive type bound*", which is also described in the book (*Item 30: Favor Generic Methods*).

Answer (score 1):

It feels a little bit weird, but this might work.

```java
abstract class Animal<T extends Animal<T>> {
    abstract List<T> animalList();
}

class Dog extends Animal<Dog> {
    @Override
    List<Dog> animalList() {
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal<Cat> {
    @Override
    List<Cat> animalList() {
    }
}
```